# «Горы грязного, потного белья свалены в...»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, перечисление

Нужна ли запятая между "грязного" и "потного"? Мне не кажется это перечислением видов белья, это как "рыжие конопатые детишки" — признаки одного предмета.
Я бы не поставила запятую. Я не права?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы совершенно правы: это не перечисление видов белья, а разные характеристики одного и того же. Поэтому запятая не нужна.