# Запятая между неоднородными определениями

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

У меня уже был похожий [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456503/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2) про неоднородные определения. Но вчера в детской энциклопедии я увидела следующее:

> Дети улиток, только что вылупившиеся из круглых(,) серебристых яиц, уже выглядят как миниатюрные взрослые.

Разве это однородные определения? С одной стороны, это же признаки одного предмета, но разве они не характеризуют предмет с различных сторон? Читала вот [тут](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=109), но что-то понятнее не стало. Стыдно признаться, но некоторые примеры я совсем не поняла. Вот, например, почему *Я пожал протянутую мне большую, черствую руку (Шол.)*, но *Большие стеклянные двери были распахнуты настежь (Кав.)*. Там сказано, что во втором случае это обозначение размера и материала, но разве в первом это не так?

А ещё [здесь](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/713-232_odnorodnye_i_neodnorodnye_opredeleniya.html) нашла пример: *Большие круглые облака.* Мол, тут цвет и форма. Так ведь и в предложении с улитками тоже.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласен с Вами — запятая между ***круглыми*** и ***серебристыми*** не нужна. Это неоднородные определения, характеризующие *яйца улиток* с разных сторон (формы и цвета).

Перед примером о ***большой*** и ***чёрствой*** *руке* в справочнике [Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=109) сказано:

> Схожесть признаков может возникнуть у прилагательных, употребляемых в **переносном** значении: ***Жестокая, студеная** весна налившиеся почки убивает* (Ахм.); *В сердце **темный, душный** хмель* (Ахм.).
>
> **Однородность** определений **подчеркивается** присоединением одного из них сочинительным союзом **и**: *В них [песнях] преобладали **тяжелые, унылые и безнадежные** ноты* (М. Г.); *Такой **мизерный, серенький и лживый** чиж* (М. Г.).

*Я пожал протянутую мне большую, чёрствую* [***и*** холодную] *руку*.

Что касается предыдущего вопроса, на который Вы ссылаетесь, то там как раз запятая выглядит совершенно оправданно: между определениями можно вставить союз ***и*** (бельё может быть грязным, но не потным, и наоборот):

*Горы **грязного, потного** белья были свалены в...*

> Однородны определения, которые выражают **схожие признаки одного предмета**, т. е. характеризуют предмет с одной стороны:
>
> ***Тяжелая, отсыревшая** стена сосняка не шевелится, безмолвствует* (Лип.).
>
> Схожесть признаков может проявиться на основе некоторого **сближения значений**.

Comment: Я нашла авторское предложение (оно без запятой; даю ссылку). _Горы грязного потного белья были свалены в чугунную ванну почти до самого потолка_ (И. Вайнберг). https://author.today/reader/48514/382367

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Спасибо. Эта тема меня давно волновала. Она не так однозначна, часто очень трудно определить, где то, а где это. Смотря как рассматривать эти определения. Вероятно, автор посчитал их разными признаками белья, но ведь можно и по-другому: _и грязное, и потное_ одновременно. И сами эти признаки уж очень близки по значению. А Юлия где-то увидела с запятой, раз задала об этом вопрос.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, а что вы думаете по поводу этого вопроса с бельём? Нужна там запятая или нет?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, интересно, что вы скажете об этом моём вопросе, учитывая то, что [тогда](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456503/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2) я с вами согласилась (и всё ещё согласна)? Мне всё же сложно увидеть эту разницу, уж слишком она для меня неуловима, я пока её не чувствую совсем.